# Can´t find stored file with Android Studio

Tags: android, file, storage

I am trying to save a file in my Android app so that I can access it using a file explorer. Since I couldn´t do this, I created a simpler app in which I only create a file and save it to see where is it stored. But I can´t see it no matter the way I do this.

Here is my code:

```
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        String myFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy";
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(myFormat, Locale.FRANCE);
        String today = sdf.format(calendar.getTime());

        //Obtiene ruta de sdcard
        File pathToExternalStorage = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        //agrega directorio /myFiles
        File appDirectory = new File(pathToExternalStorage.getAbsolutePath() + "/biciMAPS/");
        if ( !appDirectory.exists() ) {
            if ( !appDirectory.mkdirs()) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "could not create directory: " + appDirectory.getAbsolutePath(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
            }
        }
        //Crea archivo
        File saveFilePath = new File(appDirectory, today + ".csv");
        Log.i("AAARCHIVOOO", saveFilePath.getAbsolutePath());
```

And this is what the Log.i shows:

```
I/AAARCHIVOOO: /storage/emulated/0/biciMAPS/24-09-2020.csv
```

I have used the ES File Explorer and I have noticed that /storage/emulated/0 is referred to the internal storage, but I can´t find the biciMAPS folder.

Any idea?

Thank you!

Comment: So help me please! I am a little bit confused on how to do it!

Comment: I have tried your code and I have checkd that the directory has been already created, but I can´t find where! I have searched by the name among all my storage and it does´t appear. I have also tried to do it again with another directory name to see if it works but it doens´t

Comment: Sorry I forgot! I have placed it in different positions just to try, However I have added one of them, before I create the file itself. My main concerned is that it appears to exist, as it shows me a path to it, but in the end, I can´t find that path/directory/file either in my device or in the virtual device.

Comment: OK now I have added it! And I can´t see the Toast, that is the directory is being create correctly right? That´s what pisses me off, that neither the file or directory appear on my storage!

Answer (score 0):

`/storage/emulated/0` is actually `/data/media` in the file-system.

Likely you have to create the file with `saveFilePath.createNewFile()`.

And maybe also put some content into it.

Comment: But I am trying to create a new directory to save some files, I don´t care right now about the content of those files.

Comment: `/storage/emulated/0 is actually /data/media in the file-system.` ??? Dont think so. Try to list it!

Comment: @blackapps Doesn't it read `emulated`? In a root shell it should be directly accessible, else only through that mount point. This doesn't even matter, while not writing out any file. Calling `new File()` obviously isn't enough to create a file and add content.